# PY script list index out of range python

Tags: python, list

I've written a simple python script for web **scraping**:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(1,3):
    url = "https://www.n11.com/telefon-ve-aksesuarlari/cep-telefonu?m=Samsung&pg="+str(i)
    html = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    list = soup.find_all("li",{"class":"column"})

    for li in list:
        name = li.div.a.h3.text.strip()
        print(name)
        link = li.div.a.get("href")
        oldprice = li.find("div",{"class":"proDetail"}).find_all("a")[0].text.strip().strip('TL')
        newprice = li.find("div",{"class":"proDetail"}).find_all("a")[1].text.strip().strip('TL')

        print(f"name: {name} link: {link} old price: {oldprice} new price: {newprice}")
```

It gives me a `list index out of range` error in the line `newprice = li.find("div",{"class":"proDetail"}).find_all("a")[1].text.strip().strip('TL')`

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: `find_all("a")[1]` – apparently `find_all("a")` returned a list that has only 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned above, your code is not returning as many elements as you expect.

`newprice = li.find("div",{"class":"proDetail"}).find_all("a")[1].text.strip().strip('TL')` This `find_all("a")` is only returning a list of 1 `<a>` tag.

Additionally, you should check which web page this is happening in. By that I mean,

```
for i in range(1,3):
    url = "https://www.n11.com/telefon-ve-aksesuarlari/cep-telefonu?m=Samsung&pg="+str(i)
```

It could also be the case that the code fails when `i=1` or when `i=2` oe both. So you should examine each web page also.